# Index of the cell containing a point after 3D Delanay triangulation

Tags: cgal

I have done 3D Delaunay Triangulation with the help of CGAL and am trying to locate the cell containing a specified point in it. I am pretty sure that `Delaunay_triangulation_3::Locate()` is what I need. However, the `Locate()` function returns a `Cell_handle` and what I need is the index of the cell containing the given point.

How does one obtain the index of the cell from a `Cell_handle` or is there other direct way to obtain the index of the cell?

Answer (score 2):

Cells have no index in CGAL.

From the Cell_handle, you can access the vertices or the neighboring cells
or any information you have previously stored in the cell
(your own index if you have put one).

Comment: Thank you. I realized that cells do not have indices in CGAL. I created std::map<Delaunay::Cell_iterator,int> index; and store indices to it by my own. It is working well.